# "No Route to host" for certain ports via certain IPs

Tags: networking, server, kubuntu

I have this weird situation where I have a MySQL server running on my laptop, and I have a VM that also runs on this laptop.

I have noticed that I can, through the VM, `ssh` to the host via host-only IP (`192.168.56.1`), but I cannot connect to the port `3306`. However, it works if I use the LAN IP address of the host!

I used the  `nc -vz` command and I get the following output from the VM:

```
[root@portal42 portal]# nc -vz 192.168.56.1 3306
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: No route to host.
[root@portal42 portal]# nc -vz 192.168.178.241 3306
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 192.168.178.241:3306.
Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.01 seconds.
[root@portal42 portal]# nc -vz 192.168.178.66 3306
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 192.168.178.66:3306.
Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.01 seconds.
[root@portal42 portal]# nc -vz 192.168.178.66 24800
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connection refused.
[root@portal42 portal]# nc -vz 192.168.178.66 24801
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connection refused.
[root@portal42 portal]# nc -vz 192.168.178.66 3307
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connection refused.
[root@portal42 portal]# nc -vz 192.168.56.1 3307
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: No route to host.
```

As you can see, if I have no service running, it just states `Connection refused` from an IP I would have had access through normally, and that is normal.

I also have a machine on the LAN from which I tried the same, and in that case, the `nz` command, using the LAN IP of the laptop, gives me `No Route to host`, BUT only for certain ports: port `80`, `25` and `22` work, but `24800` and `3306` do not, although I do have services working on those ports. Below, `...66` is the Wi-Fi and `...241` is the wired (I have both attached).

```
$ nc -vz 192.168.178.66 61616
nc: connect to 192.168.178.66 port 61616 (tcp) failed: No route to host
$ nc -vz 192.168.178.66 3306
nc: connect to 192.168.178.66 port 3306 (tcp) failed: No route to host
$ nc -vz 192.168.178.66 24800
nc: connect to 192.168.178.66 port 24800 (tcp) failed: No route to host
$ nc -vz 192.168.178.66 80
Connection to 192.168.178.66 80 port [tcp/http] succeeded!
$ nc -vz 192.168.178.66 22
Connection to 192.168.178.66 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
$ nc -vz 192.168.178.66 25
Connection to 192.168.178.66 25 port [tcp/smtp] succeeded!
$ nc -vz 192.168.178.241 3306
nc: connect to 192.168.178.241 port 3306 (tcp) failed: No route to host
```

I have disabled `ufw`, I have flushed `iptables` on my laptop:

```
$ sudo iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Also, my MySQL is with `bind_address=0.0.0.0` and `ufw` disabled:

```
$ sudo service ufw status
● ufw.service - Uncomplicated firewall
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ufw.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2019-06-25 21:30:35 CEST; 17h ago
     Docs: man:ufw(8)
  Process: 339 ExecStart=/lib/ufw/ufw-init start quiet (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 20404 ExecStop=/lib/ufw/ufw-init stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 339 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 24 22:40:18 mau-Precision-7520 systemd[1]: Started Uncomplicated firewall.
Jun 25 21:30:35 mau-Precision-7520 systemd[1]: Stopping Uncomplicated firewall...
Jun 25 21:30:35 mau-Precision-7520 systemd[1]: ufw.service: Succeeded.
Jun 25 21:30:35 mau-Precision-7520 systemd[1]: Stopped Uncomplicated firewall.
Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

There are no indications in the logs whatsoever and `apparmor` is also removed.

This problem happened after an upgrade of Ubuntu, but I cannot figure out what the issue is!

Any help please? It is 5 days that I noticed this and I cannot fathom what can be the problem!

Thanks